# LinearFit, are constraints possible?

Tags: fitting, constraint

```
 data = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60.27}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 12.72}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 13.5.}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 19.77}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 21.90}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 22.28}}

lm = LinearModelFit[data, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7}]
```

> LinearModelFit::rank: The rank of the design matrix 5 is less than the number of terms 8 in the model. The model and results based upon it may contain significant numerical error.

I only have a small data set. I receive this error when attempting to fit.

Is it possible to apply constraints in `LinearModelFit`? I know it is possible in `NonLinearModelFit`.

I want to apply the constraint `x2 = x3 = x4` and `x5 = x6 = x7`.  Is this possible?  Would this remove the error message?

Comment: Yes.  Just create your data in the form `{x1,x2+x3+x4,x5+x6+x7}`.  But even then you have 5 parameters to estimate with just 6 sample points.

Comment: this removes the error, eliminate columns where the data has only a single value `LinearModelFit[data[[All, {2, 4, 5, 7, 8}]] , {x2, x4, x5, x7}, {x2, x4, x5, x7}]`  You do not have enough information to say anything about the missing terms.

Comment: my column elimination result is the same as the full result (with error message) if you insert `x1->1` , by the way.

Comment: If I change my data set to: {{25.32, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 607}, {25.32, 0., 0., 0., 13.36, 0., 0., 1282}, {25.32, 0., 0., 0., 13.36, 0., 8.69, 1627}, {25.32, 13.21, 0., 0., 13.36, 0., 8.69, 2143}, {25, 13.21, 0., 8.94, 13.36, 0., 8.69, 2109}, {25.32, 13.21, 0., 8.94, 13.36, 0., 8.69, 2170}}, so now values not one or zero but other values. Could I apply the same method, as the two correct answers below?  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of `LinearModelFit` contains the regressors in the model and they are constructed as arbitrary functions of the variables in the dataset:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Thus, changing the second argument of `LinearModelFit` to `{x1, x2 + x3 + x4, x5 + x6 + x7}` (that is, defining the three regressors as $f_1 = x1$, $f_2 = x2 + x3 + x4$, and  $f_3 = x5 + x6 + x7$) and using the option `IncludeConstantBasis -> False` (because your data already has a constant column), you can get the desired result without having to make any changes to your source data:

```
lm2 = LinearModelFit[data, {x1, x2 + x3 + x4, x5 + x6 + x7}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7}, 
       IncludeConstantBasis -> False];

Normal[lm2]
```

> 51.8398 x1 + 7.94734 (x2 + x3 + x4) - 22.2595 (x5 + x6 + x7)

```
lm2["BestFitParameters"]
```

> {51.8398, 7.94734, -22.2595}

A simpler alternative to get the same result is to exclude `x1` form the set of regressors:

```
lm3 = LinearModelFit[data, {x2 + x3 + x4, x5 + x6 + x7}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7}];

Normal[lm3]
```

> 51.8398 + 7.94734 (x2 + x3 + x4)- 22.2595 (x5 + x6 + x7)

```
lm3["BestFitParameters"]
```

> {51.8398, 7.94734, -22.2595}

Comment: I can't see how you achieved to move  (x2 + x3 + x4) and (x5 + x6 + x7) into the brackets?  Did you miss this part of the code off?

Comment: Thank you for adding the extra explanation and the effort you've made. It is really useful to have this method. That has clarified the situation. I think I must have misread your previous message, as I am sure I saw {x1, x2 , x3 , x4, x5 , x6 , x7}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7}, and not {x1, x2 + x3 + x4, x5 + x6 + x7}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7}.  I'll go to get my eyes tested!

Comment: If I change my data set to: {{25.32, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 607}, {25.32, 0., 0., 0., 13.36, 
  0., 0., 1282}, {25.32, 0., 0., 0., 13.36, 0., 8.69, 
  1627}, {25.32, 13.21, 0., 0., 13.36, 0., 8.69, 2143}, {25, 
  13.21, 0., 8.94, 13.36, 0., 8.69, 2109}, {25.32, 13.21, 0., 8.94, 
  13.36, 0., 8.69, 2170}}, so now values not one or zero but other values.  Could I apply the same method?

Comment: @SPIL, thank you for the accept. Both methods should work for your new data set.

Answer (score 4):

To get a fit with no warnings (which does not imply you get an adequate fit), you'll still need to remove `x1` as it is a constant.  Here is one such fit:

```
data2 = Table[{Total[data[[i, {2, 3, 4}]]], 
   Total[data[[i, {5, 6, 7}]]], data[[i, 8]]}, {i, Length[data]}]
(* {{0,0,60.27},{0,1,12.72},{0,2,13.5},{1,2,19.77},{2,2,21.9},{2,2,22.28}} *)
lm = LinearModelFit[data2, {x234, x567}, {x234, x567}];
lm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {51.839843750000014, 7.947343749999994, -22.259531250000002} *)
```

***Update***

Here is some loose algebra to show why the desired constraints can be implemented by summing some of the predictor variables to result in a simpler model where $a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_{234}$ and $a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_{567}$:

[image: Algebra]

Comment: Thanks Jim, that is really useful.  The added algebra will come in useful too.

Comment: If I change my data set to: {{25.32, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 607}, {25.32, 0., 0., 0., 13.36, 0., 0., 1282}, {25.32, 0., 0., 0., 13.36, 0., 8.69, 1627}, {25.32, 13.21, 0., 0., 13.36, 0., 8.69, 2143}, {25, 13.21, 0., 8.94, 13.36, 0., 8.69, 2109}, {25.32, 13.21, 0., 8.94, 13.36, 0., 8.69, 2170}}, so now values not one or zero but other values. Could I apply the same method?

Comment: Certainly.  I recommend @kglr 's approach as you don't have to create a separate dataset.  But, still, just having 6 data points and 4 parameters is expected a bit much.